# How to share asset requests between components using react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am looking for a good way to **share a single asset request/response** between any number of consumers using hooks.

In the code snippet provided, I use the URL to keep track of the number of components that are requesting the same asset. I store the request and if component 2 makes the same request before component 1 unmounts, component 2 will **use the cached request**. If all components are unmounted, we can abort the request and remove it from the cache.

```
/*
 * Share asset requests between components.
 * const { data, loaded, total, error } = useAssetLoader('largeFile.tiff', 'arraybuffer');
 */

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import request from 'superagent';

// Keep track of how many instances are using a each request
// when all instances have been unmounted, we can abort the request
const instances = {};

// Keep track of requests to share between instances
const requests = {};

export default function useAssetLoader(url, responseType) {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState();
  const [total, setTotal] = useState();
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!url) {
      return () => {};
    }

    const key = url + responseType;

    instances[key] = (instances[key] || 0) + 1;

    if (!requests[key]) {
      requests[key] = request(url);

      if (responseType) {
        requests[key].responseType(responseType);
      }
    }

    requests[key].on('progress', (event) => {
      if (event.direction === 'download') {
        setLoaded(event.loaded);
        setTotal(event.total);
      }
    });

    requests[key].on('error', setError);

    req.then(response => setData(response.body || response.text));

    return () => {
      instances[key] -= 1;

      // When all components are unmounted we can abort request
      if (instances[key] === 0) {
        delete instances[key];

        if (requests[key]) {
          requests[key].abort();
          delete requests[key];
        }
      }
    };
  }, [url, responseType]);

  return { data, loaded, total, error };
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I would like to use this pattern for other asynchronous tasks as well.

Comment: This is the best way. Context mentioned answers so far is just over complicating things

Answer (score 0):

You can use context to share data that is "global" to all the Components. 
`AssetLoaderContext.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

//Add all states that you want to share over here. 
const defaultState = { data: {}, instances: {}, requests: {} }
const AssetLoaderContext = React.createContext(defaultState)

class AssetLoaderProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    data: {},
    instances: {},
    requests: {}
  }
  setContextState = args => {
    this.setState(args)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <AssetLoaderContext
        value={{
          setContextState: this.setContextState,
          ...this.state
        }}>
        {children}
      </AssetLoaderContext>
    )
  }
}

//We're making a different file so the index.js/App.js doesn't get cluttered.
//You can also put all your context files in one folder and name it "context" so all 
//the "global" and shared state is in one place. 

export default AssetLoaderContext
export { AssetLoaderProvider }
```

`SomeComponent.js`

```
import AssetLoaderContext from './context/AssetLoaderContext'
//other imports

class SomeComponent extends React {
  static contextType = AssetLoaderContext
  state = {
    date: {}
    // ....etc
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.context)
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    const assetLoader = this.context
    // do stuff with this.props.url, this.props.responseType.
    //Then set the AssetLoaderContext state. 
    const data = this.state.data
    assetLoader.setContextState({
      data
      // etc.
    })
  }
  render() {
    //you can just get the context in OtherComponent without passing it here. 
    return <OtherComponent />
  }
}
```

`App.js`

```
import AssetLoaderProvider from './context/AssetLoaderContext'

//At the top level wrap your components in AssetLoaderProvider so each
//component can be a "consumer" of the data provded by the context. 
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <AssetLoaderProvider>
      <App />
    </AssetLoaderProvider>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

To clear the context, you can just call `setContextState({data: {}, instances: {}, requests: {})` or write a designated `clearContextData` method.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which was about how to use *hooks* to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

You were definitely on the right track, but you'll want to use the `useContext` hook, along with `useState` and `useEffect`. Let's start with a helper hook that takes a context and a request and returns a context provider that will eventually provide the data:

```
export const useFetchContext = (
  Ctx,
  request,
  initialData = null,
) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(request);
        const json = await response.json();
        setData(json);
      } catch (err) {
        // handle error
      }
    };

    if (!data) getData();

  // currently only runs once. Add request and data as dependencies
  // in the array below if you'll be feeding it a stateful request.
  }, []);

  const CtxProvider = ({ children }) => {
    return <Ctx.Provider value={data}>{children}</Ctx.Provider>;
  };

  return CtxProvider;
};
```

Now that we have some re-usable logic for fetching and sticking the result in a context provider, we'll need to feed it some stuff so we can use it:

```
import { useFetchContext } from './path/to/file';

const dataContext = React.createContext();
export const useDataContextProvider = () => useFetchContext(dataContext, url);
export const useDataContext = () => useContext(dataContext);
```

Rinse and repeat for each file that fetches something you want available globally. You can even move up a step to e.g. index.js and wrap your `<App />` component in the provider(s) So they aren't clogging up your JSX.

So now you've got a helper that fetches the data and returns a provider when you feed it a context, a hook that uses it (useDataContextProvider), and a hook that 'unwraps' the global context data (useDataContext).

So, in App.js:

```
import { useDataContextProvider } from './path/to/file';

export default () => {
  const CtxProvider = useDataContextProvider();
  return (
    <CtxProvider>
      <YourComponentsHere />
    </CtxProvider>
  );
};
```

The children of the provider will now have access to the data (once the fetch completes) via the other hook. So in the components you want to use the context:

```
import { useDataContext } from './path/to/file';

export default ({
  someProp
}) => {
  // This will be undefined, or whatever you set as the default,
  // until the fetch completes. Don't try to e.g. destructure it.
  const contextData = useDataContext();
  return <SomeJSX />;
};
```

Comment: This is interesting but doesn't share requests between components.

If `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` both use `useDataContextProvider` with the same URL, two requests will be made.

Comment: Turn data to an object with the `key` as the url. Change condition to `if (!data[url])`. So the request will only be made if the url key doesn't exist. In the component, use useEffect with data as a dependency to get the data after it has been fetched.